# Does every business logic needs to be a service in symofny2?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I am learning `Symfony2` and I find the dependency injection stuff and service container interesting.

But I want to know if I should make all my logic in the service container and then call it form controller or I could use the old way ( make classes and instantiate them when I need ) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what says the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#what-is-a-service) on this topic,

"*The advantage of thinking about "services" is that you begin to think about **separating each piece of functionality in your application into a series of services**. Since each service does just one job, you can easily access each service and use its functionality **wherever you need it**. Each service can also be more easily tested and configured since it's separated from the other functionality in your application. This idea is called **service-oriented architecture** and is **not unique to Symfony2** or even PHP. **Structuring your application around a set of independent service classes is a well-known and trusted object-oriented best-practice**. These skills are key to being a **good developer** in almost any language.*"

---

**Put another way**, Turn the common logic (used globaly in your application) into services is a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, the role of the container is to make available to the whole application all the common logic.

It acts as a substitute to all global arrays ($_REQUEST, $_GLOBALS, etc...), to global variables, global constants (as opposed to class constants, which remain useful), global functions and all such things that makes PHP a rather messy language. It aims at making PHP the full OOP language it wants to be.

It incites one to avoid procedural programming that PHP still allows, and that is good.

In short, you can still instanciate and use classes the usual way. But whenever you spot two pieces of code alike, or using a same logic, or reusing the same information, that generally means you want to use the service container to help reusing the code.